# Magento compilation causes errors

Tags: magento

Magento 1.4.2

Having compilation errors and the page doesn't render. I get errors but I believe it is deeper than this module:

```
2012-04-02T15:26:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: require_once(cloudfiles.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/spasandstuff.com/includes/src/OnePica_ImageCdn_Model_Adapter_Rackspace.php on line 20

Line 20 is: require_once 'cloudfiles.php';
```

I tried removing the module and the page now renders, but if I go to Magento Connect I get a blank page and this error:

```
2012-04-02T16:07:30+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: require_once(/var/www/spasandstuff.com/includes/downloader/pearlib/php/PEAR.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/spasandstuff.com/includes/src/Varien/Pear.php on line 60

Line 60 is: require_once $_pearPhpDir."/PEAR.php";

This line is how it is finding the path:
$_pearDir = dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . DS . 'downloader' . DS . 'pearlib';
```

So there appears to be some sort of pathing issue. If anyone could help me track down what might be causing the problem, it would be greatly appreciated as I have no idea where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not having any performance issues with your site, I would suggest disabling the compilation mode within Magento, as it is meant to speed up the including of needed files instead of the auto loader searching through numerous code pools.

System->Tools->Compilation, and disable.

If you require compilation to be enabled for speed / performance issues, I would suggest reading over the below article for more insight.

Alan has a good write up on using the compilation compiler within Magento.
http://alanstorm.com/magento_compiler_path

Comment: Thanks that is exactly the info I needed to dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

If disabling compilation doesn't fix the error try to find the existence of that module in core_config_data and remove the entries from there..it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

place a # before the “require_once” statements. They are not needed when using the Magento/Zend Framework with the "lazy loading" option of Zend Loader. On top of that, they  break the way compilation works. Its a performance issue:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/performance.classloading.html